# SmartMonTools: tests get cancelled without any traces

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl, smartmontools

I am testing hard disks with [SmartMonTools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) under Ubuntu 20.04.

Tests for some hard disks are not working - they disappear without leaving any warnings or errors.

Hard drive status before the test (note the time **Sun Mar 13 16:25:12 2022 UTC**):

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-104-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     MB4000GDUPB
Serial Number:    26F5K1J3F17A
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 6db900727
Firmware Version: HPG3
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Mar 13 16:25:12 2022 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 532) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0025) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0007   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   100   002    Pre-fail  Always       -       11957
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       41134
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   105   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
180 Unknown_HDD_Attribute   0x003b   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Min/Max 8/58)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     41109         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     41038         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Begin the **long** test:

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-104-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF OFFLINE IMMEDIATE AND SELF-TEST SECTION ===
Sending command: "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in off-line mode".
Drive command "Execute SMART Extended self-test routine immediately in off-line mode" successful.
Testing has begun.
Please wait 532 minutes for test to complete.
Test will complete after Mon Mar 14 01:17:34 2022 UTC
Use smartctl -X to abort test.
```

Check the test status - test is in progress (time **Sun Mar 13 16:26:05 2022 UTC**):

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-104-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     MB4000GDUPB
Serial Number:    26F5K1J3F17A
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 6db900727
Firmware Version: HPG3
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Mar 13 16:26:05 2022 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 249) Self-test routine in progress...
                    90% of test remaining.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 532) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0025) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0007   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   100   002    Pre-fail  Always       -       11957
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       41134
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   105   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
180 Unknown_HDD_Attribute   0x003b   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       36 (Min/Max 8/58)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Self-test routine in progress 90%     41134         -
# 2  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     41109         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     41038         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Check the test progress again - **no tests running** (time **Sun Mar 13 16:26:46 2022 UTC**):

```
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-104-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     MB4000GDUPB
Serial Number:    26F5K1J3F17A
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 6db900727
Firmware Version: HPG3
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Mar 13 16:26:46 2022 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 532) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0025) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0007   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   100   002    Pre-fail  Always       -       858
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       41134
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   105   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
180 Unknown_HDD_Attribute   0x003b   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       32 (Min/Max 8/58)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%     41109         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     41038         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

In short:

- Sun Mar 13 16:25:12 2022 UTC: no tests running.
- Sun Mar 13 16:26:05 2022 UTC: long test running.
- Sun Mar 13 16:26:46 2022 UTC: no tests running, no test results recorded.

How can I find out **why those tests get cancelled - any logs available**???

Comment: Instead of -t long you can try selective -t select,0-max. Technically this does the very same thing as -t long but it might have a more accurate progress report in the Selective self-test log section, and you could pinpoint where the test disappears. I use selective self-test with smaller slices for short tests. A long test run just takes ages on xx TB HDDs and not every machine runs 24/7 to let it finish.

Comment: @emk2203
Thank you for response. I don't have those drives anymore (replaced), will keep your suggestions in mind for the future tests.